# PHP echo many times. How to transform <?php echo $xxx; ?> in a simple shortcut like {xxx}?

Tags: php

sorry about to ask that maybe newbie question, but i believe an easy way to do it already exists and I just don't know correct term to search about this.

If we have a PHP lang file and we load this by a command, after that we really need to echo variable every time we need?

That's my question. There is anyway to change this:

```
<?php
    include('lang_en.php');
?>
<html>
    <p><?php echo $lang['word01']; ?></p>
</html>
```

For this:

```
<?php
    include('lang_en.php');
?>
<html>
    <p>{word01}</p>
</html>
```

All times need to echo a variable, need to open and close PHP tags again, it's boring.

The way of "short tags" I already know, but some servers don't accept short tags.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: `<?= $lang...` works on all servers if the PHP version is >= 5.4 (and if it isn't, MOVE ASAP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every PHP instance starting with `5.4` will accept the following

```
<p><?= $lang['word01'] ?></p>
```

If your PHP version is older than `5.4` you should strongly consider updating before you add more complexity to your codebase. `5.4` was released in early 2012 and has been past its end of life for almost a year already.

If array syntax takes too long to type, you may find object syntax faster, especially if you shorten your variable name.

```
<?php    
    include('lang_en.php');
    $l = (object)$lang;
?>     
<html>
    <p><?= $l->word1 ?></p>
</html>
```

Comment: I wold like to create a function for that, like template engines do. I believe that's more easy because i'm not using .tpl or .html, my other files is .php too. I tried a lot to do it, but really, i can't!

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these template engine:

[twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org)
[dwoo](http://dwoo.org)
[top 5 php template engines](http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/top-5-php-template-engines/)

Comment: I know some template engines, but if I go in this way, ill need to much files to migrate to a template engine. If there is anyway to get these functions from template engines and adapt to my code, maybe will be better. Anyway ill try to see that codes from template engines. Thank you for try to help!